# Signout from Grafana Iframe - Keycloak

Tags: iframe, oauth, keycloak, grafana

I have an Angular App with a Keycloak authentication system (keycloak-angular)

I have a Grafana server which allow authentication with OAuth Keycloak

I have a Keycloak Server with a realm called master, and two cliendID , one for my angularApp, and one for my grafana server.

In my angular App, I display some iframes coming from my Grafana Server, and with my actual configuration, my Iframes are directly authenticated with OAuth (there is no login screen).

I have a logout button in my angular App to process a Keycloak logout, which redirects me to the keycloak login screen.

My problem is that Iframe sessions are saved when I perform a keycloak logout, and if after that I login with a different user, my grafana iframe will still be authenticated with the previous user.

If I logout inside the grafana app, or the grafana iframe, or go to http://grafana-server:3000/logout , I will get logged out to Grafana, and the grafana iframe session will switch to the new one (the user which is logged in my angular app).

I want the grafana iframe to perform a sign out when I logout from my Angular App, so the next user logged in will not have the session of the previous user.

Grafana OAuth Section :

> ```
> [auth.generic_oauth]
> name = OAuth
> enabled = true
> allow_sign_up = true
> client_id = grafana
> client_secret = my-secret
> scopes = openid email profile
> email_attribute_name = email:primary
> email_attribute_path = 
> login_attribute_path =
> name_attribute_path =
> role_attribute_path =
> id_token_attribute_name =
> auth_url = http://keycloak-server/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth
> token_url = http://keycloak-server/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
> api_url = http://keycloak-server/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
> allowed_domains =
> team_ids =
> allowed_organizations =
> tls_skip_verify_insecure = false
> tls_client_cert =
> tls_client_key =
> tls_client_ca =
> auto_sign_up = true
> ```

[image]
Here is a screenshot from the keycloak conf for the grafana client.

The backchannel logout url seems to be the solution but I can't find how to use it properly.

I tried to set this url as "/logout" ; "http://grafana-server:3000/logout" ... I have no idea how to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OIDC logout has `redirect_uri` parameter, where user is redirected after logout, so use it to logout from Grafana as well. Desired flow:

1. Angular logout redirects browser to OIDC logout `https://keycloak-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=<grafana logout url>` (of course `grafana logout url` is URL parameter so it must be URL encoded)
2. Keycloak after succesfull OIDC logout redirects browser to `<grafana logout url>` ("your" http://grafana-server:3000/logout), because it was instrumented to do that with `redirect_uri` parameter
3. Grafana executes logout (Grafana user session in the browser will be destroyed) and browser will be redirected to Grafana login page (that can be of course customizes with `signout_redirect_url` config)

Comment: It works but it gave me another problem that a specified in an answer post.

Comment: @SonnyJayet so it will be nice if you accept my answer, because it works. And it will be nice to have "goodbye" route in the angular app (available without auth), where you can redirect user at the end with nice message that logout was succesfull. You didn't specify in your question, where do you want to redirect user at the end, but IMHO ending on Keycloak login page can be confused for me as the user. You have full control with `signout_redirect_url` where user will be redirected at the end.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended to to is the following :

> ```
> let redirectUrl =`${environment.keycloak.url}/realms/${environment.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=${encodedGrafanaLogoutUrl}`
> keycloakService.logout(redirectUrl)
> ```

When I logout, my browser is redirected to the grafana logout url, but does not redirects me to the angular app again.

To do so, I set the <signout_redirect_url> of grafana config file with the url of my angular app.

It works and I get redirected to the app after login out. So I finally don't use the backchannel logout.

The problem is that now, a logout from the Grafana web app will redirect me to the angular app.